# How to hide the three dots displayed on the top area of the ipad swift

Tags: swift, xcode, ipad, splitview

I was not able to find the name of the icon displayed on the top of the iPad, but I want to know how to hide the three-dots stuff in a specific view controller programmatically.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if you can as they are a system button. Have you tried setting the app to be full screen?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71541747/1852207.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is possible to hide the split view control button.

In the info page of your application's target it should allow you to set that the application `Requires full screen`.

[image]

This should remove the dots from the top.

**Though it will mean that your application cannot support split view.**

---

Tested on Xcode 13.1 and iPadOS 15.2

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to hide the three dots now!!
This is exactly what I was looking for!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, you can't. It's part of Apples new internal UI.  wants to make sure that users have a set of gestures/options that are the same on all apps (like swiping up to send an app into background) to help users navigate.